# Wanted to grep the BINARY.ear md5sum value inside the md5sum.txt file

Tags: grep

I have a file called `md5sum.txt` which contain below

```
f64e7c803e4fb1207b785dff19232a1e  AM-BINARY.ear
1403519c6276b2e446d2c8cef3be0e5d  BINARY.ear
```

I want to grep only the md5sum value of `BINARY.ear`, but when I grep the the `BINARY.ear` it gives me the value of `AM-BINARY.ear` also.

```
[provider@MPSGSPLUNK01 test]$ grep -F 'BINARY.ear' md5sum.txt | awk '{print $1}'
f64e7c803e4fb1207b785dff19232a1e
1403519c6276b2e446d2c8cef3be0e5d
```

Answer (score 2):

Just `grep` with `' BINARY.ear'`?

```
grep -F ' BINARY.ear' md5sum.txt | awk '{print $1}'
```

Or `awk` only solution:

```
awk '$2 == "BINARY.ear" { print $1 }' md5sum.txt
```

Comment: Thank you yaegashi, appreaciate your help it's really works now.                                                                             [provider@MPSGSPLUNK01 test]$ grep -F ' BINARY.ear' md5sum.txt | awk '{print $1}'
1403519c6276b2e446d2c8cef3be0e5d